# Preserving original value of string and decode it like a json

Tags: php, json

I want preserve original value of target field and use json_decode to use following string as object:

```
{
    "translatorID": "f4a5876a-3e53-40e2-9032-d99a30d7a6fc",
    "label": "ACL",
    "creator": "Nathan Schneider",
    "target": "^https?://(www[.])?aclweb\\.org/anthology-new/[^#]+",
    "minVersion": "1.0.7",
    "maxVersion": "",
    "priority": 100,
    "browserSupport": "gcs",
    "inRepository": true,
    "translatorType": 4,
    "lastUpdated": "2012-01-01 01:42:16"
}
```

Comment: How do you decode it, code please.

Comment: How are you getting the JSON? It works fine for me here: http://codepad.org/io4wUjxc

Comment: I am sure an identical question to this was asked a short while ago under a different username. (EDIT) It seems to have been deleted.

Comment: The thing is - if the **input** had those 2 back-slashes, it's fine, but if you type the two back-slashes in a string, it's actually **one** backslash, escaped... to make two backslashes, you need to write 4 of them actually

Comment: ``\.`` is an invalid escape sequence in JSON. Not even http://jsonlint.org/ would validate the JSON you have now. Your earlier version with two slashes (``\\.``) was ok, but **not** if it is inside a PHP string. In that case, you have to escape the backslashes as I did in my demo. The backslash is the escape character in strings, hence `"\\."` would produce `\.` which is invalid in JSON as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do before parsing with `json_decode` is:

```
$string = str_replace('\\', '\\\\\\\\', $string);
var_dump(json_decode($string, true));
```

This must be a bug in the json parser.
The method is not very clean but at least you're getting your results.

Comment: I made my answer based on his input string, and with my replacement I get the right result.

Comment: His input is valid json, but if he types the same in a **string** value in code, and not reading it from a file/db/whatever, then he needs to double the amount of backslashes himself

Comment: @Reza it returned NULL with any other combination.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try stripping the slashes off?

This worked for me :

```
$string = '{
    "translatorID": "f4a5876a-3e53-40e2-9032-d99a30d7a6fc",
    "label": "ACL",
    "creator": "Nathan Schneider",
    "target": "^https?://(www[.])?aclweb\.org/anthology-new/[^#]+",
    "minVersion": "1.0.7",
    "maxVersion": "",
    "priority": 100,
    "browserSupport": "gcs",
    "inRepository": true,
    "translatorType": 4,
    "lastUpdated": "2012-01-01 01:42:16"
}';

var_dump( json_decode(stripslashes ($string)));
```

Comment: This changes orginal value of target

Comment: A tedious solution could be to use addcslashes and some regex to escape the characters that are being unescaped by stripslashes on the resulting array/object.